# Tensorflow's Estimator.evaluate(): Is the accuracy "global" or specific to the batch it saw?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've checked through stack overflow as best I can and the Tensorflow API's section on Estimator.evaluate() but haven't been able to find anything addressing this question.

I'm a student working on a research project with Tensorflow, I've been tracking accuracy with evaluate() and storing that value that's returned in a text file. My advising professor (who works with ML/NNs but not specifically python and Tensorflow) wants to know if that accuracy value is specific to the batch of data it saw in the moment, or if it's the overall accuracy of that network from inception to that moment in time.

Can someone please clarify whether 'accuracy' is a measure of the accuracy for that given batch of data at the moment of evaluation OR is it a measure of all batches/data that it has seen up to and including that moment?

If it is NOT a measure of all batches, is there any way to find that from the network or do I need to be manually calculating it?

On how I've been building/training my network (in case it matters): I build the model at a slightly lower level than Keras (as in, I define the architecture in a method using tf.layers), I also have never explicitly run the network with tf.session() (I've only run into trouble when I've tried and past networks have functioned fine without it).

Answer (score 1):

Estimator.evaluate() calls *input_fn* in each step which returns one batch of data as can be seen in the document https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#evaluate. So what your *input_fn* returns is important here i.e if test data is small, it can return entire data OR it can return data in batches if test data is large.

If your test dataset is small enough to fit in memory (RAM), *input_fn* returns all test data at once, you can pass it once and get result

e.g.
result = classifier.evaluate(test_inpf)

Now if your test data is large not to fit in the memory, to get accuracy over entire test dataset, you can get accuracy on each batch (because *input_fn* will be returning batches now) and take running average over all batches in your dataset.
e.g. If your test dataset has 100 examples. Batch size is 10.
For every batch of size 10, you evaluate accuracy. You get 10 accuracy values for dataset. Then average of these is accuracy of model over entire dataset.

This is also a helpful tutorial on TensorFlow website
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/linear